# Como pegar o valor de cada TD dentro de cada TR de maneira dinamica usando jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte HTML de exemplo:

```
<tr>
    <td>Futebol</td>
    <td>Campo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Volei</td>
    <td>Quadra</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Tenis</td>
    <td>Saibro</td>
    <td>Campo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Natação</td>
    <td>Piscina</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Ciclismo</td>
    <td>Rua</td>
</tr>
```

Eu precisaria percorrer as `tr` pegando o valor de cada `td` e ter um `json` mais ou menos assim:

```
"esportes":[
{
    "esporte":"Futebol",
    "ambiente":"Campo"
},
{
    "esporte":"Volei",
    "ambiente":"Quadra"
},
{
    "esporte":"Tenis",
    "ambiente":"Saibro",
    "ambiente":"Campo"
},
{
    "esporte":"Ciclimo",
    "ambiente":"Rua"
}]
```

Como eu poderia fazer isso com jQuery?
Fiz apenas isso por enquanto mas não sei como continuar a partir daqui (caso eu esteja no caminho). Transformar para JSON não é bem o problema, o problema maior seria pegar os valores da maneira correta, cada esporte com seu ambiente de uso:

```
$("#tableEsportes > tbody > tr").each(function(){ 
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Link útil: https://jsonlint.com permite que você valide seu json tem uma breve explicação sobre Json

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Primeiramente, **JSON não pode ter chaves repetidas:**

```
"ambiente":"Saibro",
"ambiente":"Campo"
```

Sugiro esta estrutura:

```
[
    {
        "esporte":"Futebol",
        "ambiente": ["Campo"]
    },
    {
        "esporte":"Volei",
        "ambiente": ["Quadra"]
    },
    {
        "esporte":"Tenis",
        "ambiente": ["Saibro", "Campo" ]
    },
    {
        "esporte":"Ciclismo",
        "ambiente": ["Rua"]
    }
]
```

Então pode usar o seletore `:first-child` para pegar apenas o primeiro `<td>` que seja filho do `<tr>` e o seletor `:not(:first-child)` para pegar os demais elementos que serão os locais:

```js
$(function () {
    var esportesJson = { "esportes": [] };

    $("#tableEsportes tr").each(function () {
        var esporte = $("td:first-child", this);
        var ambientes = [];
        
        $("td:not(:first-child)", this).each(function () {
            ambientes.push($(this).text());
        });
        
        esportesJson.esportes.push({
            "esporte": esporte.text(),
            "ambiente": ambientes
        });
    });

    console.log(esportesJson);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tableEsportes">
<tr>
    <td>Futebol</td>
    <td>Campo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Volei</td>
    <td>Quadra</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Tenis</td>
    <td>Saibro</td>
    <td>Campo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Natação</td>
    <td>Piscina</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Ciclismo</td>
    <td>Rua</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Muito bom! Vai ser útil para um projeto meu no futuro. +1 :)

Comment: Muito bom, era exatamente isso que precisava para funcionar. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

A [resposta do Guilherme](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/279443/como-pegar-o-valor-de-cada-td-dentro-de-cada-tr-de-maneira-dinamica-usando-jquer/279449#279449) da está muito boa, mas outro maneira de ser fazer usando JavaScript puro:

```js
var arrayTr = document.body.querySelectorAll('#tableEsportes > tbody > tr');
var array = [];

for (let i = 0, j = arrayTr.length; i < j; i++) {
    let obj = {};
    let ambientes = [];
    let tr = [];

    tr = arrayTr[i];
    obj.esporte = tr.children[0].textContent;

    for (let x = 1, y = tr.children.length; x < y; x++) {
        ambientes.push(tr.children[x].textContent);
    }

    obj.ambiente = ambientes;
    array.push(obj);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```

```html
<table id="tableEsportes"> 
<tr>
    <td>Futebol</td>
    <td>Campo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Volei</td>
    <td>Quadra</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Tenis</td>
    <td>Saibro</td>
    <td>Campo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Natação</td>
    <td>Piscina</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Ciclismo</td>
    <td>Rua</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Explicando

- Retorne todas as linhas com [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)
- Deduzindo que a primeira coluna sempre será o esporte, as próximas devem ser o ambiente então utilize outro for para percorrer o restante das colunas.
- Use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) para transformar seu `array` em um `string` no formato **JSON**.

Comment: Troque `innerHTML` pelo `textContent` por favor :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento qual a diferença?

Comment: Marconi innerHTML pegaria qualquer conteudo HTML injetado ali, já o textContent pega apenas o texto, ignorando as tags HTML (textContent é equivalente ao innerText). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML vs https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento bacana, obrigado pela dica :), código alterado!

Comment: Tá ai o +1 merecido :D

Comment: Muito bom @Marconi. +1 :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento valeu :)

Comment: @JorgeMatheus valeu :)

Comment: @Marconi fiz alguns ajustes no código, se desejar pode reverter, mas são apenas para micro-otimizações

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento bacana e meu obrigado, já deixei o +1 na sua resposta!

Answer (score 0):

Pode fazer assim: criar um array e adicionar os elementos a ele e depois serializar:

```js
var obj = {
esportes: []
};
$("#tableEsportes > tbody > tr").each(function() {
var linha = {
    esporte: $(this).find('td').eq(0).text(),
    ambiente: $(this).find('td').eq(1).text()
}
obj.esportes.push(linha);
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableEsportes">

<tr>
    <td>Futebol</td>
    <td>Campo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Volei</td>
    <td>Quadra</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Tenis</td>
    <td>Saibro</td>
    <td>Campo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Natação</td>
    <td>Piscina</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Ciclismo</td>
    <td>Rua</td>
</tr>
</table>
```